# How to access the variable from one class to other in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I want to access the variable UniversityId in the class of `_HomePageState`

```
class showDetailOfUniversity extends StatelessWidget {

   final String UniversityId;

  showDetailOfUniversity({Key key, @required this.UniversityId}) : super(key: 
      key);

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context)
 {

    return  (
      HomePage()
    );

  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override

  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();

}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

//   
    var temp2 = showDetailOfUniversity();

   var temp = temp2.getUniversityId;

  /// here i want to access the code but failed

}
```

Comment: How did it fail, what error do you have?

Comment: contructor is called from somewhere else. so its mean value is present in the UniversityId variable so now we have to access the variable in the class "_HomePageState"
So when i access the variable "temp" it simple display null value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you created another instance of `showDetailOfUniversity` that will have another values for its members. You did not initialize `String UniversityId` so its value is null untill you set it.

So when you called `showDetailOfUniversity()` in `temp`, the value of `String UniversityId` in this instance is null since there was no value given in this particular instance.

You can pass the `String UniversityId` in the constructor of the `StatefulWidget` like this:

```
class ShowDetailOfUniversity extends StatelessWidget {
  final String universityId;

  ShowDetailOfUniversity({Key key, @required this.universityId})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomePage(universityId: universityId);
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String universityId;

  const HomePage({Key key, this.universityId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var universityId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    universityId = widget.universityId;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Text(universityId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your code:

```
var temp2 = showDetailOfUniversity(UniversityId: university_id);

var temp = temp2.UniversityId; //this will return university_id
```

Comment: contructor is called from somewhere else. so its mean value is present in the UniversityId variable so now we have to access the variable in the class "_HomePageState"